# How do you specify the location of a "Product" in Schema.org?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm setting some Microdata for products sold by 3rd parties. I have the location of the product (as the buyer might want to physically pick it up) and the username of the seller. But all other information is product specific.

Is there was a correct way to specify that a product was located in a specific location or should I just include it and not mark it up with Microdata?

This is my code so far:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <img itemprop="image" src="ad-image.jpg" />
  <span itemprop="name">Name of item</span>

  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="AUD" />
    <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
    <span itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition">New</span>
    <span itemprop="model">2010</span>
    <meta itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
  </div>

  <span itemprop="description">The description....</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microdata don't allow such markup in its vocabulary. You could specify where the manufacturer is from, but that doesn't seem to help you.

You could of course use a seperate [Place](http://schema.org/Place) item to mark the cordinates. But you wont have the opportunity to use it as a property to the [Product](http://schema.org/Product) item in the way you describe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`availableAtOrFrom` property](http://schema.org/availableAtOrFrom):

> The place(s) from which the offer can be obtained (e.g. store locations).

It takes a [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) as value.

Note that it has to be added to the `Offer`, not the `Product`.